# Is asking for a list of discussions "Subjective and argumentative"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, not-constructive

The question [Where can I find good discussions of PHP vs Ruby vs Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241961/where-can-i-find-good-discussions-of-php-vs-ruby-vs-python) was closed as "Subjective and Argumentative".

While I understand that discussions aren't welcome *within* Stack Overflow, that shouldn't mean that links to discussions aren't welcome. You wouldn't close questions asking for links to blogs or podcasts merely because you shouldn't blog within Stack Overflow, so why should it be different for discussions?

Or is there some other reason that the question was closed?

[image: A painting of a pipe, with Ceci n'est nas une pipe underneath it]

Comment: Well, PHP is for script kiddies and isn't a serious programming language, Ruby don't scale and Python... well, Python devs are all buttheads.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly is it that you want to know?

**Are you trying to choose between the two?**

If so then try posting a more specific "which one should I choose?" question detailing **specifics** about your project or situation, or if you are just learning for the sake of it be specific about what you already know and what you want to learn.

Bear in mind that your question is still fairly likely to be closed, but might fare a little better if it is more specific.

**Are you trying to understand the syntax / technical differences between the language?**

If so then again be **specific** about what it is you want to know:

**Bad:**

- Which is faster?
- Why does X not have Y?

**Good:**

- Are there available benchmarks of the performance between x and y?
- In **X** I can do **Z** using, **Y** how do I do this in **W**?

Ultimately the trick to asking this sort of question is weighting it so that it **can't** just degenerate into an X vs Y argument.  Being specific about exactly what it is that you need to know is the only way to avoid the inevitable pointless subjective argument bound to follow. (don't think links to X vs Y arguments don't count!)

Remember: If a question *can* turn into a subjective argument then it *will* - If it's going to turn into an argument then it's going to get closed.

Comment: I think the person who asked the question (not me!) was after the differing philosophies of the languages.